# sbt: cyclic dependence between modules?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to have cyclic dependence between modules of a multi-module project?

Here is an example:

```
lazy val client = (project in file("client"))
  .dependsOn(service)
  .settings(...)

lazy val service = (project in file("service"))
  .dependsOn(client)
  .settings(...)
```

Im getting an error `recursive value x needs type` which I think is due to this recursive definition, but not completely sure (there might be some other weird phenomenon causing this).

Comment: can we have the full compilation error and when it's occured ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why you ever need this? No build system provide support for cyclic dependencies, because its impossible to maintain correct build order in such case. If your module *service* depends on part of *client*, then you should move it out to a separate module (usually we call it *common*):

```
lazy val common = (project in file("common"))

lazy val client = (project in file("client"))
  .dependsOn(service, common)
  .settings(...)

lazy val service = (project in file("service"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(...)
```

Also, it's considered as a good practice to have separate sub-modules for service API and service implementation (*service-api* and *service-impl*). This way allows to decouple client from service implementation details