# How to import class from other directory in scala?

Tags: scala, import, package, sbt

I need to make use of the UIController class in the PriceAlert Class, but it is not possible, even though they are in the same package: co.uproot.abandon.
The thing is I can use the PriceAlert class in the UIController class but not the other way around.

[files layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi4pu.png)

Comment: This is probably a sign of bad design if you need to use a controller class from somewhere else. It's a good thing that you code is splitters into module preventing such imports.

Answer (score 2):

Look [dependence of modules](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) in your root `build.sbt`. It's possible that `gui` depends on `base` so you can use `PriceAlert` from `base` inside `UIController` from `gui`.

If you need to use classes from different modules in each other then this means that you have cyclic dependence of modules

[sbt: cyclic dependence between modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762532/sbt-cyclic-dependence-between-modules)